# Using a python root logger with robot framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, automation, robotframework

I'm using Robot Framework to run python scripts that I've made and I'm running into an issue when I try to do logging through a custom root logger that I've been using to output my python logging in a desired format. If I don't use a root logger RF will output my logs just fine, but if I use my root logger then RF doesn't output and of the logging done by my python scripts. Here's my code:

logger.py:

```
import logging.config
import os

_WORKSPACE = os.getenv(
    'WORKSPACE',
    default=R'C:\opt\ci\jenkins\workspace\Killer_Automation_Robot'
    )

def _get_named_logging_config(test_name):
    named_logging_config = dict(
        version = 1,
        disable_existing_loggers = False,
        formatters = {
            'file': {
                'format': '[%(asctime)-s] {%(filename)-30s:%(lineno)-3d} %(levelname)-8s - %(message)-s'
            },
            'console': {
                'format': '[%(asctime)-s] {%(filename)-30s:%(lineno)-3d} %(levelname)-8s - %(message)-s'
            }
        },
        handlers = {
            'default': {
                'level': 'INFO',
                #'level': 'DEBUG',
                'formatter': 'console',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            },
            'file': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'formatter': 'file',
                'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                'filename': ''.join([
                    _WORKSPACE,
                    R'\{!s}.log'.format(
                        test_name
                        ),
                    ]),
                'mode': 'w',
                'encoding': 'utf-8'
            },
        },
        loggers = {
            '': {
                'handlers': ['default','file'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True
            },
            'hammer': {
                'handlers': ['default'],
                'level': 'WARN',
                'propagate': False
            },
        },
        root = {
            'handlers': ['default','file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    )
    return named_logging_config


def instantiate_logger(name):
    named_logging_config = _get_named_logging_config(
        ''.join([
            'robot_',
            name,
            ])
        )
    return named_logging_config

def make_logging():
    named_logging_config = instantiate_logger('do_math')
    logging.config.dictConfig(named_logging_config)
    log = logging.getLogger('')
```

do_something.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library    do_math

*** Test Cases ***
Logging test
    do logging
```

do_something.py:

```
import logger
import logging

logger.make_logging()
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info('Starting {!s}'.format('Install Software Test'))

class do_math(object):

    def __init__(self):
        log.info('Starting {!s}'.format('do math'))

    def do_logging(self):
        log.info('this log worked')
        self.do_math1()

    def do_math1(self):
        log.warning('this is a warning')
```

When I run this using the do_something.py, nothing at all is logged. However, when I run do_something.py by itself, I get the expected output with all the logs. Also, If I take away the **logger.make_logging()** line in the python file that instantiates the root logger and run the RF file, RF outputs all the logs but obviously not in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a little workaround. All I had to do was add a function **attach_to_logger()** in my logger.py that gets and returns a global log variable, and then call upon that function in any method that does logging in my do_something.py. Feels a little hack-y but it works fine for me.

logger.py:

```
#attach_to_logger() has been added
def instantiate_logger(name):
    named_logging_config = _get_named_logging_config(
        ''.join([
            'robot_',
            name,
            ])
        )
    return named_logging_config

def make_logging():
    named_logging_config = instantiate_logger('do_math')
    logging.config.dictConfig(named_logging_config)
    log = logging.getLogger('')

def attach_to_logger(name):
    global log
    make_logging()
    log = logging.getLogger(name)
```

And then all I have to do in my module is call attach_to_logger() whenever I need to do any logging.

do_something.py:

```
import logger
import logging
class do_math(object):

    def do_logging(self):  
        log = logger.attach_to_logger(__name__)
        log.info('Starting {!s}'.format('Do Something test!'))
        log.info('this log worked')
        self.do_math1()

    def do_math1(self):
        log = logger.attach_to_logger(__name__)
        log.warning('this is a warning')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced to the same issue, where I don't want to make our testing library dependend on robot logger, rather than define a logging handler for robot framework.

Luckily there is [a logging Handler already implemented in robot](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/src/robot/output/pyloggingconf.py#L57). Thus simply referencing them in your dict (for `dictConfig()`) does the trick to forward py standard logging to log.html of RF. Here is a sample dict to be loaded:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "format": "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)-8s [%(name)s] %(message)s"
        },
        "nameAndMessage": {
            "format": "[%(name)s] %(message)s"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "default"
        },
        "file": {
            "formatter": "default",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "robot_pcc_atom_dev.log"
        },
        "robotHandler": {
            "formatter": "nameAndMessage",
            "class": "robot.output.pyloggingconf.RobotHandler"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {
            "handlers": [
                "file", "robotHandler"
            ],
            "level": "DEBUG"
        },
        "asyncio": {
            "level": "WARN"
        },
        "aiohttp": {
            "level": "WARN"
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Doing so you'll find very soon that `RobotHandler` does not support the formatters (in the example above named `nameAndMessage`).

Issue + Fix you'll find here: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/3208

**Edit2: Sample Code improvement**
I made a new formatter called `nameAndMessage` because in the robot log.html output the time and log level is already integrated.